# Check whether all unique value of column B are mapped with all unique value of Column A

Tags: python

I need little help, I know it's very easy I tried but didn't reach the goal.

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
data1 = [['India', 350], ['India', 600], ['Bangladesh', 350],['Bangladesh', 600]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Country', 'Bottle_Weight'])
data2 = [['India', 350], ['India', 600],['India', 200], ['Bangladesh', 350],['Bangladesh', 600]] 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Country', 'Bottle_Weight'])
data3 = [['India', 350], ['India', 600], ['Bangladesh', 350],['Bangladesh', 600],['Bangladesh', 200]] 
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns = ['Country', 'Bottle_Weight'])
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

So basically I want to create a function, which will check the mapping by comparing all other unique countries(Bottle weights) with the first country.

- **According to the 1st Dataframe,** It should return text as - All unique value of 'Bottle Weights' are mapped with all unique countries
- **According to the 2nd Dataframe,** It should return text as - 'Country_name' not mapped 'Column name' 'value'

  - In this case, 'Bangladesh' not mapped with 'Bottle_Weight' 200
- **According to the 3rd Dataframe,** It should return text as - All unique value of Bottle Weights are mapped with all unique countries (and in a new line) 'Country_name' mapped with new value '200'

Comment: Can you make your problem easier to reproduce with samples of the dataframe, not images?

Comment: I have added the code that I have used to create those data frames. @yatu

Comment: I don't see how you are expecting a different result for the 2nd and 3rd dataframe. In both cases you have one country with [200, 350, 600] and the other with [350, 600]. What distinguishes those two cases?

Comment: @bisen2 because we will compare with the first country's unique Bottle_Weight with all others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a particularly efficient algorithm, but I think this should get you the results you are looking for.

```
def check_weights(df):
    success = True
    countries = df['Country'].unique()
    first_weights = df.loc[df['Country']==countries[0]]['Bottle_Weight'].unique()
    for country in countries[1:]:
        weights = df.loc[df['Country']==country]['Bottle_Weight'].unique()
        for weight in first_weights:
            if not np.any(weights[:] == weight):
                success = False
                print(f"{country} does not have bottle weight {weight}")
    if success:
        print("All bottle weights are shared with another country")
```